# 3D plot of a generated 2D matrix

Tags: python, matrix, plot

I've written a code for my school project. The u and v matrices are generated already. I've made a 2D contour, but I wish to plot u and v in 3D.

```
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#inputs
m = 40
n = 20
Uinf = 2
delX = 0.05
delY = 0.05
nu = 0.8e-2
u= np.zeros((m+1,n))
v= np.zeros((m+1,n))
#intializing boundry conditions
u[:,0] = v[:,0] = v[:,n-1] = v[0,:] = 0
u[:,n-1] = u[0,:] = Uinf
#main program
for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(1,n-1):
        a = (nu*delX) / (u[i,j]*delY**2)
        b = (v[i,j]*delX) / (2*u[i,j]*delY)
        u[i+1,j] = (a-b)*u[i,j+1]+(1-2*a)*u[i,j]+(a+b)*u[i,j-1]
        v[i+1,j] = v[i+1,j-1]-(delY/(2*delX))*(u[i+1,j]-u[i,j]+u[i+1,j-1]-u[i,j-1])
```

I have to mention that I don't wanna generate an arbitrary function; u[i,j] and v[i,j] are present.
Thanks!

Comment: You need to add more detail regarding what You want and what you have tried. The general procedure is to try something  (for instance, Google for an existing answer). Then if it doesn't work, ask a question why it is not working. You should not expect somebody to generate a full solution for you.

Comment: I've looked for a solution in here and Google as well, but they just generated a random function and then plot it with an arbitrary mesh. I have the mesh already, the mesh is the matrix dimension!